# Creation of a chronological series with R

Tags: r

I have chronological data from 2020-03-02 to 2020-06-02.
How to create a time series of daily frequency and efficiently with the ts () function of R.

Here is my proposition:

```
# Data Import
codecovid19_SN <- read.csv("confirmes.csv", sep = ",", header = T)

# Date format 'as.POSIXct()'
covid19_SN <- covid19_SN %>%
mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date)) %>%
arrange(date)

# Time series
ts_covid19 <- ts(covid19_SN[,2:ncol(covid19_SN)], start = c(3,1), frequency = 
30)
```

Besides, I tried to draw the series using the 'autoplot ()' function of the 'fpp2' package

```
g <- autoplot(ts_covid19[,3], col = "brown") +
ggtitle("Testés positifs du COVID-19 au Sénégal\n depuis le début Mars 
2020") +
xlab("Mois") +
ylab("Nbre de cas") +
theme_minimal()
```

[evolution of positive cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l854C.jpg)

Can you help me display the date labels on the x-axis.